# PYTHON dictionary and look up table

Tags: python, dictionary

This is my first post and am new to programming so please excuse my novice mistakes in asking a question:

I have two files in the tabular format:

`IDs.txt` is just a list of IDs that looks like this:

```
1
2
3
4
7
```

`dictionary_FE.txt` is a dictionary of sorts with 2 columns that are tab delimited and looks like this:

```
1    a
2    b
5    h
7    g
```

where a key is associated with a value.  I would like to write a python code to get me a new file that takes the IDs in `IDs.txt` and looks them up in `dictionary_FE.txt`.  Not all the IDs in `IDs.txt` will be in `dictionary_FE.txt`.  I would like a file that looks like this:

`File3.txt` as output:

```
1    a    
2    b
3    'not found'    
4    'not found'    
7    g
```

The following is what I have written:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

infile1=open("dictionary_FE.txt", "r")
infile2=open("IDs.txt", "r")

F=infile1.readlines()

for item in infile2.readlines():
    item=item.strip()                       
    for line in F:
        line=line.strip()
        line=line.split('\t')
        ide=line[1]
        if item == ide:
            print line[0]+"\t"+item
```

I get a blank output.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this isn't a code-writing service

Comment: I have tried writing a code but it doesn't work...the following is what I have:#!/usr/bin/env python

infile1=open("dictionary_FE.txt", "r")
infile2=open("IDs.txt", "r")

F=infile1.readlines()

for elto in infile2.readlines():
 elto=elto.strip()      
 for line in F:
  line=line.strip()
  line=line.split('\t')
  ide=line[1]
  if elto == ide:
   print line[0]+"\t"+elto

Comment: Please **edit the question** with a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); code is tricky to read in comments. Also, what does *"doesn't work"* actually *mean*? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected output (provide input and expected and actual output)?

Comment: sorry for the mistakes.  I get a blank output.

Comment: You should e.g. `print item, ide` to see what's going on, then the error would be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
table = {}
with open('File2.txt') as f_in:          # Generates the dictionary
    for line in f_in:
        line = line.strip()
        table[line.split('\t')[0]] = line.split('\t')[1]


with open('File1.txt') as f_1, open('File3.txt', 'w') as f_2:   # Matches against the dictionary
    for line in f_1:
        key = line.strip()
        if key in table: 
            f_2.write('%s\t%s\n'%(key,table[key]))
        else:
            f_2.write("%s\t'not found'\n"%key)
```

Comment: thank you for the reply.  I tried and I only get an output of the IDs that are 'not found' in file2.txt.

Comment: @rod12160: Worked fine for me. Make sure that characters in File2.txt are separated by tabs or blank spaces.

Comment: it works when i create sample files like those I have in my question!  I guess it's my input files that are screwed up.  THANK YOU THANK YOU!

Comment: wish I could give you a +1 but I guess I can't do that until I have 15 reputation points.  I really appreciation your help though.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just open the second file once,
2. parse over it,
3. and then loop over the first file,
4. and then simultaneously compare the values from the second to the first,
5. and write the results in the third.

And that's it.

```
file2dict = {}
with open('File2.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        l = line.split()
        file2dict[l[0]] = l[1]


with open('File1.txt', 'r') as f:
    with open('File3.txt', 'w') as f3:
        for line in f.readlines():
            l = line.split()
            if l[0] in file2dict:
                f3.write('%s %s\n' %(l[0], file2dict[l[0]]))
            else:
                f3.write("%s 'not found'\n" % l[0])
```

Comment: thank you very much for the reply, but I only get an output with the first hit that is 'not found'

Comment: @rod12160: Apologies, I made an error. Fixed it, so try it now.

Comment: same thing happens as before.  I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @rod12160: I downloaded the files, and ran my code - I get the correct results that you state that I should.

Comment: YES jrd1 you are right...I did the same with your code as I did with the other code on here and works fine with those files.  Something is going on with my input file.  THANK YOU so much.  and sorry to everyone else who gave me a negative :(

Comment: wish I could give you a +1 but I guess I can't do that until I have 15 reputation points.  I really appreciation your help though.

Comment: @rod12160: Glad to know you were able to resolve the issue. :) Regarding the upvoting, I understand.